# Nonlinear second order IVP

Tags: calculus

I would like know if next ODE is of type Mathieu-Duffing or type van der Pol and how I can show that it has a unique maximal solution ?
Please excuse my poor English
Thank you

`$$u^{\prime \prime}(t)+(t-k)u(t)-u^{3}(t)=0$$

$u(0)=a$, and $u^{\prime}(0)=0$

where $a$ and $k$ are real parameters.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Could you tell us where this problem is coming from? Also, please explain your question. A "maximal" solution can mean several things: A solution with maximal amplitude or a solution with a maximal domain of existence.

Comment: Thank you very much Hans Engler
I apologize for not replying in time because I was disconnected:
This problem was given to me by a student who told me that this is the first question in a subject of entrance examination to a French school. I ask because I have not done a lot of non-linear analysis.
Maximum solution in French jargon, is a solution that can not permissible to prolonged. I think his interval of existence is maximum. Regards